# Use VBA to create Outlink Calendar Entry containing a link

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using VBA to create an entry in an Outlook Calendar. This works fine. I would like the Calendar entry to contain a link to another document. What is the syntax for adding a link to the Body field of an Outlook Calendar entry?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the WordObject associated and then have to associate the text with a hyperlink.

You could do the following:

```
Dim objInsp as Object, objDoc as Object
Set objInsp = appointmentItem.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor

link = "http://www.yourlink.com"
linkText = "LinkText"
Set selection = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
objDoc.Hyperlinks.Add selection.Range, link, "", "", linkText, ""
```

(**[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx)**)